# Preference для бедных. Ищу класс для хранения простых типов данных

Tags: java, поиск-библиотек

Ищу класс для хранения простых типов данных. Всё, что мне надо от этого класса - это приблизительная реализация следующего интерфейса

```
interface Data {
    putString(String key, String value);
    putInt(String key, int value);
    // и так для всех примитивных типов
    getString(String key);
    getLong(String key);
    // ...
}
```

Что есть похожего в jdk, guava или, может быть, в некой другой библиотеке?

Comment: Что мешает создать свой? Например инкапсулировав в классе Map'ы нескольких типов?

Comment: @Xoxole, совершенно ничего. Но зачем делать велосипед?

Comment: В стандартном `jre` такого нет. Но ты можешь наследоваться от `java.util.Properties` и допилить туда свои методы.

Answer (score 0):

В стандартном `jre` такого нет. Но ты можешь наследоваться от `java.util.Properties` и допилить туда свои методы.

Нечто подобное есть в [Apache Commons Collection](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) в классе [ExtendedProperties](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties.html). Но это только до  версии 4.x. С версии 4.x он удалён и рекомендуется использовать [PropertiesConfiguration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/PropertiesConfiguration.html) из [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/)

Или же ты можешь найти себе более подходящую версию из списка классов реализующих [ImmutableConfiguration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/ImmutableConfiguration.html)